How to draw a large number of circles/spheres in matplotlib efficiently?
I want to make a simulation of a large number of particles colliding with each other in matplotlib (on the order of ~10,000 particles). I want to make both 1D, 2D, and 3D simulations and I am struggling with how to draw a large number of particles with a given radius efficiently. In 1D and 2D, I figured out that my best bet is to use a CircleCollection or a PatchCollection to draw the particles efficiently. However, these Collection classes only support 2D shapes as much as I understand, so I don't know what to do in 3D. I think the only reliable way to draw many points in 3D is by using scatter, but this introduces a new problem: scatter accepts its marker size in points**2 and not data coordinates. Since my particles are going to collide, it's important that their visual radius will match their actual collision radius. I couldn't find out how to convert a radius in data coordinates to a marker size in points**2, and I couldn't find any other tools to draw a large number of 3D balls in matplotlib.
Can somebody show me an example of how to draw a large number of 3D particles with a given radius in data coordinates? Or alternatively, explain how I can convert such a radius to a marker size for scatter.
For example, I have the following 3D scatter, and I want the marker size to be points_size = 0.3 in data coordinates. In other words, the balls should be 0.3 of the side of the box containing them:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

points = rng.random((5, 3))
points_size = 0.3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

ax.scatter(
    points[:, 0],
    points[:, 1],
    points[:, 2],
    s=points_size,  # Wrong since I want `points_size` radius in data coordinates
)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I can't figure out how to convert points_size to a marker size for scatter. Alternatively, if someone knows another way to draw many 3D balls that allows me to control their radius in data coordinates, it would also be good.

It would be helpful to provide a [mre] (i.e. minimal code to set up a small example of a dataset and current approach(es) to graph your data).

@mozway I added a MWE.
